# Joplin no longer works after updates Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, application-launch, appimage

I am using Arch Linux 5.16.9-arch1-1, and after updates joplin-desktop never started anymore.
In fact if I try to start it from cli the following is returned:

```
[19009:0218/094941.146523:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(442)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
/usr/bin/joplin-desktop: line 12: 19009 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) ./@joplinapp-desktop "$@"
```

I tried also to update it using `wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laurent22/joplin/dev/Joplin_install_and_update.sh | bash` posted on official repo on github (https://github.com/laurent22/joplin), without any change.

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.